# Masked TextBox with differing sized text

Tags: wpf

OK, I admit this is an unusual case!  I need a masked TextBox in which groups of different characters are different sizes.  The text has to be selectable as a single block for copy / paste / delete purposes.

I'm not sure how I'd go about this in WPF.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change from `TextBox` to `RichTextBox`. In a richtextbox, you can control format of parts of the text.